# TFS 2010 branching and merging

Tags: tfs

I am new to source control and have a question.  I have a TFS project that already has dev, test, and prod branches.  I have fixed a bug in the dev branch, and now I need to get the changes in the test branch.  Do I just do a "Merge" with the test branch as the target?  After that, will test and dev then be identical at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether they are after the merge absolutely equal or not depends on how they were constructed, their previous checkins etc.
In order to make sure, you could perform the merge & then (before checking-in!) compare the folders with a Tool like Windiff.

Answer (score 0):

You have to see how you create the dev branch if you created from test branch you can do what you say and then after successfully merge, you will merge the change back to the test branch, in other words when you create branch from source you merge the branch witch the source and than merge back the source to the branch to reflect the source merge changes to the branch

Thanks

M.Radwan